# Simplify sum of quadratic forms to have matrix variable $\sum_i x_i^T A_i x_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms

Let $A_i$ be a square symmetric matrix of size $n \times n$ and $x_i$ be the $i$-th row of matrix $X$ of size $m \times n$.

Consider $f(x_1, x_2,...,x_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i^T A_i x_i $.

I need to reformulate $f$ as a function of $X$, which means the formula of $f$ should not contain any $x_i$. Instead, it should contain only $X$.

An attempt is to flatten $X$ as a column vector (called $x$), and create a block diagonal matrix $A$, of which diagonal blocks are $A_i$. Then $f(x_1, x_2,...,x_m) = f(x) = x^T A x$. But I need $X$ to be a matrix having $x_i$ as its rows. So I'm stuck here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could write the function as $$f(X)=\sum_{k=1}^m{\rm Tr}\Big({\rm Diag}(e_k)XA_kX^T\Big)$$ where $\{e_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors.

Comment: You could also flatten and sum the $\{A_k\}$  $$S=\sum_{k=1}^m{\rm vec}(A_k)\,e^T_{k+km-m}$$ and then write $\,f(X)={\rm Tr}\big((X\otimes X)S\big)$

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you don't mind, please write those comments as an answer so I can tick this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k^{th}$ ***row*** of the matrix $X$, expressed as a *column* vector is 
$$ x_k = X^Te_k $$ 
where $\{e_k\}$ are the standard basis vectors for ${\mathbb R}^m$

It will prove convenient to use a colon as an inline product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(AB^T)$$
Now perform a step-wise transformation of the function of interest 
$$\eqalign{
f
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m x_k^TA_kx_k \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m e_k^TXA_kX^Te_k \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m (XA_kX^T):(e_ke_k^T) \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m (X\otimes X){\rm vec}(A_k):{\rm vec}(e_ke_k^T) \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m (X\otimes X)\,a_k:e_{(k+km-m)} \cr
 &= (X\otimes X):\Bigg(\sum_{k=1}^m e_{(k+km-m)}a_k^T\Bigg) \cr
 &= (X\otimes X):S^T \cr
 &= {\rm Tr}\Big((X\otimes X)S\Big) \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:** At the beginning of the derivation, the symbol $e_k$ was used as a basis vector for ${\mathbb R}^m$. Midway through the derivation, the symbol $e_{(k+km-m)}$ is used as a basis vector for ${\mathbb R}^{m^2}$.

Comment: nice! Would you mind writing down explicitly what S is, possibly if it can be constructed in a simple form? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the simplest expression that I can think of  
$$\eqalign{
s &= {\rm vec}(S) = \sum_{k=1}^m e_k\otimes e_k\otimes {\rm vec}(A_k) \\
S &= {\rm vec}^{-1}(s) \\
}$$